# Why does activator add itself to the new project?

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I just started learning Play Framework. I read I should use `activator new` command to create a new project. This resulted in different folders and files being created. But Activator also copied itself to the project folder. I see:

```
activator
activator.bat
activator-launch-1.3.6.jar
```

in my project folder.

Also different files were automatically included in `.gitignore`, but these files not.

What is the reason behind this? From my point of view it's like Maven binary copied itself inside project, so it does not make much sense for me.

Should I use this activator script instead of the one installed in my system?
If I want to change Maven version I install new binaries and I change the folder the symbolic link points to (this link is used in `$PATH` in bash configuration). What if I would like to change the version of activator I use? I should `git remove` this one and `git add` new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This done for allow to run project from the system where activator is not installed.

From the typesafe [documentation](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/docs) (**Re-Launching Activator** section):

> To make it easy for others to launch Activator for your application
>   you can put the activator, activator.bat, and
>   activator-launch-VERSION.jar files in your SCM.

So many templates add this files to SCM. You can delete them from your application if you do not like them.

> Should I use this activator script instead of the one installed in my system?

No. It's only for easy using of other users. i.e. you download the project and can run it without installing activator (it's will run from the project source)